# How to reorganize/filter hash values

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes:

```
data = [{"user_id"=>1, "answer"=>"cupcakes"},
 {"user_id"=>1, "answer"=>"Colorado"},
 {"user_id"=>1, "answer"=>"newspaper"},
 {"user_id"=>2, "answer"=>"fruitcake"},
 {"user_id"=>2, "answer"=>"Louisiana"},
 {"user_id"=>2, "answer"=>"tv"}]
```

How can I reorganize this so that it is grouped by `"user_id"` and lists all the `"answer"`s in one hash? Something like:

```
output_data = [{"user_id" => 1, "answer1"=>"cupcakes", "answer2"=>"Colorado", "answer3"=>"newspaper"},
{"user_id" => 2, "answer1"=>"fruitcake", "answer2"=>"Louisiana", "answer3"=>"tv"}]
```

Or maybe have all the answers in an array:

```
output_data = [{"user_id" => 1, "answers"=>["cupcakes", "Colorado", "newspaper"]},
{"user_id" => 2, "answers"=>["fruitcake", "Louisiana", "tv"]}]
```

I'm not tied to this specific output. I do need to have the `"user_id"` as a key and all the answers organized together. Any suggestions?

Comment: The `output_data` above is incorrect (hash can not contain same keys). What you are looking for is [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).

Comment: @mudasobwa yes, you are right. it was late when I asked the question. I clarified the question a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do that as follows:

**Code**

```
def convert(arr)
  arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
    h.update(g["user_id"]=>[g["answer"]]) { |_,o,n| o+n }
  end.map { |k,v| { "user_id"=>k, "answer"=>v } }
end
```

**Example**

```
convert(data)
  #=> [{"user_id"=>1, "answer"=>["cupcakes", "Colorado", "newspaper"]},
  #    {"user_id"=>2, "answer"=>["fruitcake", "Louisiana", "tv"]}]
```

**Explanation**

We have:

```
enum = data.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] })
  #=> #<Enumerator: [{"user_id"=>1, "answer"=>"cupcakes"},
  #                  {"user_id"=>1, "answer"=>"Colorado"},
  #                  {"user_id"=>1, "answer"=>"newspaper"},
  #                  {"user_id"=>2, "answer"=>"fruitcake"},
  #                  {"user_id"=>2, "answer"=>"Louisiana"},
  #                  {"user_id"=>2, "answer"=>"tv"}]:
  #   each_with_object({})>
```

We can convert the enumerator to an array to see what values will be passed into the block:

```
a = enum.to_a 
  #=> [[{"user_id"=>1, "answer"=>"cupcakes"}, {}],
  #    [{"user_id"=>1, "answer"=>"Colorado"}, {}],
  #    [{"user_id"=>1, "answer"=>"newspaper"}, {}],
  #    [{"user_id"=>2, "answer"=>"fruitcake"}, {}],
  #    [{"user_id"=>2, "answer"=>"Louisiana"}, {}],
  #    [{"user_id"=>2, "answer"=>"tv"}, {}]]
```

As you see, the enumerator contains six elements, each a two-element array comprised of an element of `data` and a hash, which is initially empty.

The key thing is that I'm using the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the value of a key when the key appears in both hashes being merged.

The first element of `enum` is passed to the block and assigned to the block variables as follows:

```
g, h = enum.next
  #=> [{"user_id"=>1, "answer"=>"cupcakes"}, {}] 
g #=> {"user_id"=>1, "answer"=>"cupcakes"} 
h #=> {}
```

The block calculation is therefore:

```
h.update(g["user_id"]=>[g["answer"]])
  # {}.update(1=>["cupcakes"])
  #=> {1=>["cupcakes"]}
h #=> {1=>["cupcakes"]}
```

`update`'s block is not used for this first merge operation because (prior to the merge) `h` does not have a key `1`. In a later operation `g["user_id"] #=> 1` again. At that time the block will be used to determine the value of the key `1`.

This results in:

```
h = data.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g["user_id"]=>[g["answer"]]) { |_,o,n| o+n }
end
  #=> { 1=>["cupcakes", "Colorado", "newspaper"],
  #     2=>["fruitcake", "Louisiana", "tv"] }
```

It is then a simple matter to map the key-element pairs of `h` to the desired array of hashes.

**Alternative**

Another way of doing this by merging hashes is as follows:

```
data.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) do |g,h|
  h[g["user_id"]] << g["answer"]
end.map { |k,v| { "user_id"=>k, "answer"=>v } }
  #=> [{"user_id"=>1, "answer"=>["cupcakes", "Colorado", "newspaper"]},
  #    {"user_id"=>2, "answer"=>["fruitcake", "Louisiana", "tv"]}]
```

This provides the hash with a default value of an empty array when `h[k]` is to be modified when `h` has no key `k`. For example:

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }
  #=> {} 
h[:cat] << 'boots'
  #=> ["boots"] 
h #=> {:cat=>["boots"]}
```

Comment: `s/answer/answers/` in the resulting dataset :)

Answer (score 5):

Your expected result does not make sense. To maintain the `"answer"` information, you need to keep them as an array.

```
data.group_by{|h| h["user_id"]}.each{|_, v| v.map!{|h| h["answer"]}}
# =>
# {
#   1=>["cupcakes", "Colorado", "newspaper"],
#   2=>["fruitcake", "Louisiana", "tv"]
# }
```

Strings such as `"user_id"` and `"answer"` are redundant, and you should avoid them being in the data unless it helps in any way to make them clear.

Comment: Nice clean solution. I would disagree that strings are redundant though, as they provide valuable context to consumers of the data structure. Could increase efficiency using symbols instead.

Comment: @fylooi, you can have your cake and eat it too by freezing strings.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: That too, though i believe the convention is to use symbols for hash keys.

Comment: @fylooi In this case, the result I showed could be named `user_id_to_answer`, and that is it. No need to have those labels for each entry.

Comment: @fylooi, I fully concur. Another advantage of symbols is that it's one less character to type.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I need to have the user_id still in the result. I like the clean solution.

Comment: analytics, could of course just tack `.map { |k,v| { "user_id"=>k, "answer"=>v } }` on after the last closing parenthesis.